# how to solve Mysql sub query

Tags: mysql

Here is a a problem

```
select stockrequest.clientnum, requestlist.productnum,requestlist.qtyrequest
from stockrequest, requestlist 
where stockrequest.requestnum = requestlist.requestnum
```

this query will result

```
client num   productnum    qty
1            123            4
2            345            5
3            456            7


select client.clientname, stockrequest.clientnum
from client , stockrequest
where stockrequest.clientnum = client.clientnum

clientname   clientnum
yd              1
myer            2
nike            3
```

i need a subquery that will replace `clientnum` to `client name` in the first query

Comment: It is not difficult to learn JOINs..

Comment: Join all 3 tables in one query. You don't need a subquery.

Comment: i join 3 table but i need to replace client num with client name

Comment: Do not use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Always use explicit JOIN... ON syntax. Then join the second table to the first, and the third table to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Do a 3-way join:

```
SELECT c.clientname, rl.productnum, rl.qty
FROM stockrequest AS sr
JOIN client AS c ON c.clientnum = sr.clientnum
JOIN requestlist AS rl ON rl.requestnum = sr.requestnum
```

Answer (score 0):

may you just select all :) (untested)

```
select s.clientnum, r.productnum, r.qtyrequest, c.clientname
from stockrequest s, requestlist r, client c
where s.requestnum = r.requestnum
```